# Behavioral modelling: syntax error, unexpected end

Tags: verilog, modelsim

```
 module seven_seg1 ( in , o );
 input [2:0]in ;
 output [6:0]o ;
 always@(*)
 begin
   case (in) 
            0:  o=7'b1111110 ;
            1:  o=7'b0110000 ;
            2:  o=7'b1101101 ;
            3:  o=7'b1111001 ;
            4:  o=7'b0110011 ;
            5:  o=7'b1011011 ;
            6:  o=7'b0011111 ;
            7:  o=7'b1110000 ;
            8:  o=7'b1111111 ;
            9:  o=7'b1110011 ;
      default: o= 7'b0000000 ;
   endcase   
 end
endmodule
```

---

I have written the above code, but ModelSim shows this error:

> Error: (vlog-13069) C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/examples/beh.v(18): near "end": syntax error, unexpected end.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get that error when running Modelsim. I do get an illegal reference to `o`. That's because you are making procedural assignments to a wire. You need to make `o` a variable by declaring it as a `reg`.

```
module seven_seg1 (
 input [2:0]in ,
 output reg [6:0]o );
 always@(*)
 begin
   case (in) 
            0:  o=7'b1111110 ;
            1:  o=7'b0110000 ;
            2:  o=7'b1101101 ;
            3:  o=7'b1111001 ;
            4:  o=7'b0110011 ;
            5:  o=7'b1011011 ;
            6:  o=7'b0011111 ;
            7:  o=7'b1110000 ;
            8:  o=7'b1111111 ;
            9:  o=7'b1110011 ;
      default: o= 7'b0000000 ;
   endcase   
 end
endmodule
```